# MSBuildWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync looking for targets in Visual Studio/v14.0

Tags: msbuild, roslyn

I have a VS 2013 console application that loads any solution(.sln) file - compiles all projects within it using Roslyn and extracts API usage information from the compilation model.

I am now facing this peculiar issue - When I run the application from within Visual Studio 2013 (using Ctrl-F5 or F5) everything works fine. I am able to compile stuff and extract all information.
However when I open a command line (cmd) and try to run this Console app from I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Impor
When I run
```

Note the ***v14.0*** there. Why does MSBuildWorkspace try to look into v14.0 directory for required target files ? Is it because I installed the MSBuild tools for CTP and the default path while I run stuff from a simple command line has changed ?

--Edit--
Here is the import

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

However I doubt it is to do with the Import statement as such. If I run the console app .exe from the "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2013" everything works fine again.

Comment: Show us the `<Import>`s in your project file.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: Not a real solution but as you mention it works from the VS Command Prompt. As a workaround I created a batch file that first calls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" and then the app runs fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can make your Web Application projects self-contained and not require Visual Studio 2015 to compile by adding NuGet reference to [MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/).

Comment: Copying/pasting from a dev machine is not a good solution, THIS is a great solution.

Comment: I added this reference but now some other 3rd party dlls are listed as "not found" or "missing". Build in VS2015 works fine but Build server complains about these 3rd party references being missing. <sigh>

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my build server. When I targeted /tv:14.0   (Tool Version 14.0 which is the Roslyn Build engine)

I resolved it by going out to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio then creating folders like v14.0\WebApplications

I then went out to my system with Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (because this is put out there by Visual Studio 2015) and copied that file out to the build servers new folder.

Comment: /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 worked, /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 failed, so I made a v12.0\WebApplications directory copying its contents from v11.0\WebApplications and the build worked (not sure what this is actually doing but it worked)

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2012 installed on your build server? Version 12 is actually Visual Studio 2013.